# How to change the background color (without code windows) in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to change the background color in Visual Studio when there are no code window.  Basically the default background of the window.  Here is a picture...

[image: Default Visual Studio window, dark theme]

The arrow is pointing to the area I would like to color.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I think, you are asking another way from light theme selection?

Comment: Yes, that would do it but my goal is to keep the dark theme, just change that background to something with a touch more green. :)

Comment: Understood, maybe an extension should be installed like that 

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.ColorThemeDesigner

Comment: That's the thing!!  That did what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stay in dark mode and try to change only some areas of color. You should try to this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.ColorThemeDesigner). Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

[Hamit Enes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3707753/hamit-enes) pointed me in the right direction.  There is an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.ColorThemeDesigner) that let's you create themes that have a much wider and clearer set of color selections.  While I could not find what I needed in the VS tools, the theme editor led me right to it.  Turns out what I need was in the "Main Window, Active Background".

Comment: Let me post an answer, if you accept. Have a good day